# How to convert query from Sql to Solr (query by row_number)

Tags: solr

I have a statement sql

```
WITH cte AS
(   
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER LastDate DESC, ) AS rn, Action  
   FROM TableA                                                  
)
SELECT cte.*
  FROM cte    
WHERE rn = 1
 AND Action <> 1
```

How could I convert to solr ?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish? If you're just returning the first row, `rows=1`, `start=0` will do that. My knowledge of MSSQL is far too limited to say anything more.

Comment: Because I have to get the first item (order by date desc) each group and then filter to get items match conditions. If I don't get the first item, the results false because it not is item newest

Comment: So you're looking to get the first for each value of a field, if that document has a specific value in another field?

Comment: Yes, I need get newest items of each group, then query another field to get last results

Comment: @MatsLindh : Do you have the solution of solr to in this situation ?